# ios - gif color changing on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, html, gif

I have a problem when creating a HTML5 app for the iPad.

I have this GIF file which is to act as a background-image where it has this animating effect of light orbs moving across a track. The thing is, whenever I click anything on the screen where it is a link or a drop down menu the background-image turns blue from red as shown in the image.

http://i1225.photobucket.com/albums/ee387/xavianaxw/photo.png

So yup! I hope someone has an idea what is going on because it's kinda my first project in my company and I don't wanna mess things up.

Comment: You are going to have to post code of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you use a true color Gif image, not a indexed Gif.

GIF is palette-based, it's not often used for truecolor images.
So maybe you need use a special tool to convert your gif image.

Comment: so i need to use an indexed gif?